# Not able to run this program?

Tags: java

Create two concrete classes of the BatAndBallGames class for the games baseball and cricket.Each concrete class should have 2 new data members and 2 new member functions.The data members and member functions in the 2 classes should not be the same.

```
import java.util.*;

abstract class BatAndBallGames

 { 

  abstract void display();
  abstract void rulesSummary();
  int PlayersPerTeam;
  int LengthOfGame;

 } 

concrete class Baseball extends BatAndBallGames

 { 
   Baseball(int a,int b)

   {

     PlayersPerTeam=a;
     LengthOfGame=b;

   }

     void rulesSummary()

   {

     System.out.println("baseball rules");

   }

     void display()

   {

 System.out.println("In baseball PlayersPerTeam=" +PlayersPerTeam + " LengthOfGame=" +LengthOfGame);

   }
 }

   concrete class Cricket extends BatAndBallGames

   { 

    Cricket(int a,int b)

     {

       PlayersPerTeam = a;
       LengthOfGame = b;

     }

       void rulesSummary()

       {

         System.out.println("cricket rules");

       }

      void display()

       { 

         System.out.println("In cricket PlayersPerTeam=" +PlayersPerTeam + " LengthOfGame=" +LengthOfGame);

      }
}



 public class BatandBall

 {
  public static void main(String args[])

  {

  System.out.println("Airtel Champions League");

  BatAndBallGames obj = new Baseball(10,3); 
  obj.display();

  BatAndBallGames obj1 = new Cricket(11,8); 
  obj1.display();

  }
 }
```

Comment: So, apart from `concrete` not been a valid identifer, why else can't you run it?

Comment: where did you read `concrete`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've dumped your code into the question - but not given us any information about what's not working. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints - make sure you clearly describe the problem, and ideally cut the code down to a *minimal* example demonstrating the problem, formatting it properly.

Comment: Odds are very good your Java compiler has already told you why you can't run this program... or at least one of the reasons why.  What did it tell you, and what part(s) did you not understand?

Comment: how to create concrete class of some abstract class >>  like in my code where i used concrete keyword ??

Answer (score 0):

We can not concrete as a keyword or identifier to define a class in java. So error is coming .
You can try like this, it is working

```
import java.util.*;

    abstract class BatAndBallGames

     { 

      abstract void display();
      abstract void rulesSummary();
      int PlayersPerTeam;
      int LengthOfGame;

     } 

    class Baseball extends BatAndBallGames

     { 
       Baseball(int a,int b)

       {

         PlayersPerTeam=a;
         LengthOfGame=b;

       }

         void rulesSummary()

       {

         System.out.println("baseball rules");

       }

         void display()

       {

     System.out.println("In baseball PlayersPerTeam=" +PlayersPerTeam + " LengthOfGame=" +LengthOfGame);

       }
     }

      class Cricket extends BatAndBallGames

       { 

        Cricket(int a,int b)

         {

           PlayersPerTeam = a;
           LengthOfGame = b;

         }

           void rulesSummary()

           {

             System.out.println("cricket rules");

           }

          void display()

           { 

             System.out.println("In cricket PlayersPerTeam=" +PlayersPerTeam + " LengthOfGame=" +LengthOfGame);

          }
 }

class BatandBall

 {
  public static void main(String args[])

  {

  System.out.println("Airtel Champions League");

  BatAndBallGames obj = new Baseball(10,3); 
  obj.display();

  BatAndBallGames obj1 = new Cricket(11,8); 
  obj1.display();

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When people talk about concrete classes, they are simply talking about classes that can be instantiated (ie you can create objects of that class). It is a concept that you need to get your head around.

There is no `concrete` keyword in java. Classes are concrete by default. This contrasts with an `abstract class`, which cannot be instantiated.

- Concrete by default
- Abstract if the `abstract` keyword is used.

In your (my guess, homework) example above, you have an abstract class `BatAndBallGame`. `Baseball` and `Cricket` are both types of BatAndBallGame, so extend from them. The reason we do this is because all bat and ball games share certain properties. However, it doesn't make sense to have an object of type `BatAndBallGame` - it isn't a real game that can be played, where as cricket and baseball are.

so you have:

```
abstract class BatAndBallGame {}
class Cricket extends BatAndBallGame {}
class Baseball extends BatAndBallGame {}
```

Comment: Actually the problem is this..>> @MichaelM..>>  Create two concrete classes of the BatAndBallGames class for the games baseball 
        and cricket.  Each concrete class should have 2 new data members and 2 new member
        functions.  The data members and member functions in the 2 classes should not be
        the same.
        
        Write main() methods that create objects of each subclass, and send them enough
        messages to show the methods work. You can also try to create an object of the
        abstract class to see what messages get printed by compilers.

Comment: Yeah I know. I'm not doing your homework for you. I was trying to explain why your solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the provided code use of 'concrete' as modifier is improper. As already mentioned by *abhishek-rana*, you can remove it and it should resolve the issue. If you were using 'concrete' as access modifier for the class, you can go to [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to know more.